# I am having difficulties run Tcl script

Tags: tcl

I have started learning TCL scripting language. I use ActivateState Tcl Devkit 5.3.0. 
When I create new simulator it gives mistake like this:

```
invalid command name "new"
    while executing
"new Simulator"
    invoked from within
"set ns [new Simulator]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command `new`in Tcl.

So it is provided by some package or by some modified shell.

Assuming you use ns2 or something like that, you need to use the appropriate shell or load the package via `package require` into a normal tclsh shell.

Comment: More particularly, `new` has no special meaning to Tcl at all (though in 8.6 it is a class method name). I'm not sure what object system defines a `new` command though; it's not part of TclOO, Itcl, XOTcl or Snit.

Comment: OTcl (http://otcl-tclcl.sourceforge.net/otcl/) as used by the NS2 network simulator has a `new` command.

Comment: In some example, they always use "new".

Comment: How can one verify the package is included properly, I have set the following line in my ./profile file "LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14". Still getting the error.

Comment: Tcl does not use LD_LIBRARY_PATH (well, only for loading .so's, with the help of the `ld` dynamic linker, thats why its called LD_LIBRARY_PATH). Usually Tcl looks into the value of the `::auto_path` global variable and the immediate subdirs for packages (e.g. pkgIndex.tcl files). If you don't see a `pkgIndex.tcl` file in your package you either need to create one or use the `load` and maybe `source` commands to load the library directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ns (i've got the exactly the same error some hours ago so i guess yes ^^ ) you can try this command :

```
ns your_tcl_script.tcl
```

And if ns is correctly installed it will make the linkage for you

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try this line below, assuming you are using ns

```
ns filename.tcl
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).